# Binding ngModel to complex data

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel, angular-components

For some time I have been researching if, and how to bind complex model to ngModel. There are articles showing how it can be done for simple data (e.g. string) such as [this](http://blog.rangle.io/angular-2-ngmodel-and-custom-form-components/). But what I want to do is more complex. Let's say that I have a class:

```
export class MyCoordinates {
    longitude: number;
    latitude: number;
}
```

Now I am going to use it in multiple places around the application, so I want to encapsulate it into a component:

```
<coordinates-form></coordinates-form>
```

I would also like to pass this model to the component using ngModel to take advantage of things like angular forms but was unsuccessful thus far. Here is an example:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="coordinates">Coordinates</label>
        <coordinates-form [(ngModel)]="model.coordinates" name="coordinates"></coordinates-form>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Is actually possible to do it this way or is my approach simply wrong? For now I have settled on using component with normal input and emitting event on change but I feel like it will get messy pretty fast.

```
import {
  Component,
  Optional,
  Inject,
  Input,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';

import {
  NgModel,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
} from '@angular/forms';

import { ValueAccessorBase } from '../Base/value-accessor';
import { MyCoordinates } from "app/Models/Coordinates";

@Component({
  selector: 'coordinates-form',
  template: `
    <div>
      <label>longitude</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        [(ngModel)]="value.longitude"
      />

      <label>latitude</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        [(ngModel)]="value.latitude"
      />
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: CoordinatesFormComponent,
    multi: true,
  }],
})
export class CoordinatesFormComponent extends ValueAccessorBase<MyCoordinates> {

  @ViewChild(NgModel) model: NgModel;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

#### ValueAccessorBase:

```
import {ControlValueAccessor} from '@angular/forms';

export abstract class ValueAccessorBase<T> implements ControlValueAccessor {
  private innerValue: T;

  private changed = new Array<(value: T) => void>();
  private touched = new Array<() => void>();

  get value(): T {
    return this.innerValue;
  }

  set value(value: T) {
    if (this.innerValue !== value) {
      this.innerValue = value;
      this.changed.forEach(f => f(value));
    }
  }

  writeValue(value: T) {
    this.innerValue = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: T) => void) {
    this.changed.push(fn);
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void) {
    this.touched.push(fn);
  }

  touch() {
    this.touched.forEach(f => f());
  }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">

  <coordinates-form
    required
    hexadecimal
    name="coordinatesModel"
    [(ngModel)]="coordinatesModel">
  </coordinates-form>

  <button type="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The error I am getting `Cannot read property 'longitude' of undefined`. For simple model, like string or number it works without a problem.

Comment: You can write a custom component that `implements ControlValueAccessor`, if that's what you mean?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes I know I can create component that uses ngModel by implementing ControlValueAccessor for simple data like string. I even gave link to article that does exactly that, but only for simple data like string or number. Is it possible to do this for custom class, like the one I showed here?

Comment: All of the interface methods are `any`, why not give it a go and see what happens? Could you expand on *"unsuccessful"* with a [mcve]?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did, I followed the article and at the end there was an error. I don't remember what was it exactly as I've already deleted the code, but latter I could do it again. Basically as I understand it, there was something wrong with the fact that my model doesn't have simply a value, but it has properties. By tomorrow I can find some time to replicate example and update the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have updated question to illustrate problem with more details. If you still need more further insight I can provide github link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` property is `undefined` at first.

To solve this issue you need to change your binding like:

```
[ngModel]="value?.longitude" (ngModelChange)="value.longitude = $event"
```

and change it for `latitude` as well

```
[ngModel]="value?.latitude" (ngModelChange)="value.latitude = $event"
```

### Update

Just noticed you're running onChange event within settor so you need to change reference:

```
[ngModel]="value?.longitude" (ngModelChange)="handleInput('longitude', $event)"

[ngModel]="value?.latitude" (ngModelChange)="handleInput('latitude', $event)"

handleInput(prop, value) {
  this.value[prop] = value;
  this.value = { ...this.value };
}
```

**[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5TaC61a6O88r7TDuOMg7?p=preview)**

**[Plunker Example with google map](https://plnkr.co/edit/MwIs5nRFx9dMkAVbwf6W?p=preview)**

### Update 2

When you deal with custom form control you need to implement this interface:

```
export interface ControlValueAccessor {
  /**
   * Write a new value to the element.
   */
  writeValue(obj: any): void;

  /**
   * Set the function to be called when the control receives a change event.
   */
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void;

  /**
   * Set the function to be called when the control receives a touch event.
   */
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void;

  /**
   * This function is called when the control status changes to or from "DISABLED".
   * Depending on the value, it will enable or disable the appropriate DOM element.
   *
   * @param isDisabled
   */
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void;
}
```

Here is a minimal implementation:

```
export abstract class ValueAccessorBase<T> implements ControlValueAccessor {
  // view => control
  onChange = (value: T) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(value: T) {
    // control -> view
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

It will work for any type of value. Just implement it for your case.

You do not need here array like (see update [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5TaC61a6O88r7TDuOMg7?p=preview))

```
private changed = new Array<(value: T) => void>();
```

When component gets new value it will run `writeValue` where you need to update some value that will be used in your custom template. In your example you are updating `value` property which is used together with `ngModel` in template.

- In my example i am drawing new marker.
- `DefaultValueAccessor` just updates `value` property https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.2.0-rc.0/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L76
- `Datepicker` in angular2 material is setting inner `value` as you do https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/123d7eced4b4f808fc03c945504d68280752d533/src/lib/datepicker/datepicker-input.ts#L202

When you need to propagate changes to `AbstractControl` you have to call `onChange` method which you registered in `registerOnChange`.

I wrote `this.value = { ...this.value };` because it is just

```
this.value = Object.assign({}, this.value)
```

it will call setter where you call `onChange` method
Another way is calling onChange directly that is usually used

```
this.onChange(this.value);
```

- Your example https://plnkr.co/edit/Q11HXhWKrndrA8Tjr6KH?p=preview
- `DefaultValueAccessor` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.2.0-rc.0/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L88
- Material2 https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/123d7eced4b4f808fc03c945504d68280752d533/src/lib/datepicker/datepicker-input.ts#L173

You can do anything you like inside custom component. It can have any template and any nested components. But you have to implement logic for `ControlValueAccessor` to do it working with angular form.

If you open some library such angular2 material or primeng you can find a lot of example how to implement such controls

Comment: Thank you for your response. It actually helped with an error but there is another problem now, it doesn't register onModelChange this way. For example if I was to add to usage example `(ngModelChange)='test("coordinates")'>` nothing would happen. Perhaps I should call somehow this `changed` Array from ValueAccessorBase or set it using this set value method. I would like to hear your opinion how it should be done in elegant and clean way. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I was so busy with my demo that I forgot to check your :)

Comment: Thank you very much for update, it really helped me. I would still have same questions if you have time:

Comment: 1. `this.value = { ...this.value };` is used to call 'set value' method, right?  
2. Is it actually correct approach to construct components like that? I have spend quite some time researching articles on that but was without luck. For me it seemed like natural way to go but now I have my doubts. Would it be something you would do in real life scenario or would you use something else.  
3. Could such a component be done using form inside? It already implements all necessary methods. I tried to do it myself but I lack technical sophistication to actually implement it.

Comment: Once again thank you very much, you really helped me out. As a final note, as I noticed no upvote of question, I wanted to ask If there is something I did wrong, or the question is too trivial. I did a lot of research and found no examples or articles that would discuss this subject. I am asking so I can improve in further questions.

Comment: Oh my God, they made it sooo complex comparing to AngularJS, why like this?.. Same worked without a line of code there.